# como abrir infowindows de google maps desde un boton?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic

Archivo .HTML donde en un ionic-radio se ejecuta un ng-repeat de los marcadores almacenados en un arreglo

```
       <div class="lista">
            <ion-scroll class="listContainer">
                <ion-list class="listoo">
                    <!--lista de los marcadores y evento click al seleccionar un marcador -->
                    <ion-radio ng-repeat="lugares in array_marcadores" ng-click="setMarcadores(lugares.posLat,lugares.posLng)"><div id="tree">{{lugares.nombre}}</div></ion-radio>
                </ion-list>
            </ion-scroll>
        </div>
```

Controlador que recibe los parametros desde el boton seleccionado.

```
     $scope.setMarcadores = function (posLat, posLng) {
        var posicion = new google.maps.LatLng(posLat, posLng);
        map.panTo(posicion);
        };
    };
```

Array donde esta contenido los marcadores, el campo nombre va a ser el contenido del infowindow

```
    $scope.array_marcadores = [
        {
            "id": "545433",
            "nombre": "GP1",
            "posLat": "10.150185152432623",
            "posLng": "-68.51857423782349"
        }, {
            "id": "545543",
            "nombre": "GP2",
            "posLat": "10.149667666876198",
            "posLng": "-68.5180538892746"
        }, {
```

Quiero que se ejecute un infowindow de acuerdo a el marcador que fue seleccionado con su respectiva descripcion